# automatic preferred max layout width before ios 8.0 in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9, xcode7

After updating Xcode 6.4 to Xcode 7, I started getting this warning in my XIBs. Although I have "relative to margin" is unchecked, I'm getting this issue.

Please help if anyone has experienced similar issue.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is a warning related to label's Width property. We need to check "Explicit" for label's width.

Comment: The "Explicit" checkbox can be found in the `Size Inspector` (right side menu, ruler icon) at the top of the menu under the `Label` section and to the right of `Preferred Width` item. *Xcode 7.1*

Comment: what would the measurement for Preferred Width in (any w and any h) size classes?, if I select explicit it is 288 value, what it means by Preferred Width what it is?